# Pandas: mapping with dict using more than 1 column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-applymap

I got basic DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6],[7, 8]],
                  index=['A','B','C','D'], columns=['X','Y'])
```

I would like the map function to work on columns X & Y and obtain this:

```
   X  Y  Chk
A  1  2  found A
B  3  4  found B
C  5  6  found C
D  7  8  found D
```

For this, I created a dict for 2 keys:

```
mapped = {1:{2:'found A'}, 3:{4:'found B'},5:{6:'found C'}, 7:{8:'found D'}}
```

And used the applymap method on the DataFrame:

```
df['Chk'] = df[['X','Y']].applymap(mapped)
```

Unfortunately, I got an error message:

```
TypeError: ("'dict' object is not callable", 'occurred at index X')
```

Is the code wrong, or is it the dict-based mapping that simply does not support more than 1 column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` and then `Series` with `MultiIndex` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = pd.DataFrame(mapped).stack().rename('Chk')
print (s)
2  1    found A
4  3    found B
6  5    found C
8  7    found D
Name: Chk, dtype: object

df = df.join(s, on=['Y','X'])
print (df)
   X  Y      Chk
A  1  2  found A
B  3  4  found B
C  5  6  found C
D  7  8  found D
```

---

If possible create `DataFrame` for mapping and then use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
mapped = {'X': [1, 3, 5, 7], 
         'Chk': ['found A', 'found B', 'found C', 'found D'],
         'Y': [2, 4, 6, 8]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(mapped)
print (df1)
       Chk  X  Y
0  found A  1  2
1  found B  3  4
2  found C  5  6
3  found D  7  8

df = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on=['X','Y'])
print (df)
   X  Y      Chk
0  1  2  found A
1  3  4  found B
2  5  6  found C
3  7  8  found D
```